# Use \singlespacing in scrheading and \onehalfspacing in the main document

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, line-spacing, setspace, scrpage2

I'm writing an article using KOMA-script `scrartcl` class. The main text uses `\onehalfspacing` option from `setspace` package. In my article I have headings with couple lines of text set up using `scrpage2` package. What I'm trying to achieve is to use `\singlespacing` only in headings.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,headlines=3,headinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{Some really long text\\ that takes\\more than one line}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I'd like that *some really long text* to have single spacing. Is it possible? Reading KOMA-script manual I didn't find anything suggesting about spacing in headings.

Comment: How about `\chead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\singlespacing\centering ..}}`?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It kind of does that, but header's top margin increases instead of heading itself shifting top. I mean, it leaves more whitespace on top of the page. Probably could be fixed by doing something with text area height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, prepend `\setstretch{1}` to the argument of `\chead`. (Don't use `\singlespacing` because that would add extra space at the start.) Second, because a singlespaced line's height is 0.8 times the height of a onehalfspaced line, change `headlines=3` to `headlines=2.4`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,headlines=2.4,headinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{\setstretch{1}Some really long text\\ that takes\\more than one line}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is it, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `\parbox`; but since `scrpage2` already uses a `\parbox` itself for placing the header, the final result will be almost unpredictable, unless we do the trick of hiding the height of the box

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,headlines=3,headinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to draw frames
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{%
  \parbox[b][0pt]{\textwidth}{
  \singlespacing\centering
    Some really long text\\
    that takes\\
    more than one line\vspace{-\dp\strutbox}
  }%
}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The final `\vspace` is meant to push the bottom line in the “really correct” position (a couple of points, actually).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since 2013 `scrpage2` is obsolete. Since version 3.24 the official successor `scrlayer-scrpage` has an option `singlespacing` to set the page head and footer in singlespacing:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,headlines=3,headinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some really long text\\ that takes\\more than one line}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]